# Can't open storyboard in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

> The document "MainStoryboard.storyboard" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error -1.)

This is the error that I see every time I click on storyboard of project.

Comment: please check if you have any git conflicts in Storyboard file

Comment: please check the Deployment target.

Comment: @Bala No there is not one!

Comment: @VineeshTP no every thing is ok

Comment: what is the deployment target ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error when opening a storyboard in Xcode 6 for the first time.

One solution is to open the storyboard with your text editor of choice and manually set auto layout to false: `useAutolayout="NO"`. Problem with this approach is that you'll loose all of your layout constraints.

Another option that worked well for me, was to install Xcode 5.1, open the storyboard and, in *File Inspector* in section *Interface Builder Document*, update *Opens in* option to use *Default (5.1)*, then open the storyboard again in Xcode 6.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the storyboard files had .XML Extension! by removing .xml extension my problem was solved.

name should be like:

```
Main.storyboard
```

and **NOT**:

```
Main.storyboard.xml
```